# Octave/Matlab read data from file as array of vectors

Tags: matlab, octave

I am extremely new to octave. I just want to do this:

I have a file in the following format:

num1 num2

num1 num2

num1 num2

num1 num2

I want an array of vectors as follows:

v[1]=[num1,num2]

v[2]=[num1,num2] 
.....and so on

People experienced with octave or matlab help.

Comment: Matlab or octave you need ?

Comment: What format is your data file? xls? csv? other?

Comment: Matlab or octave both have the same syntax for matrices. For example the 1st answer below works with both matlab and octave so please if you don't know how to dont rate -1 this question. This is a correct question and has a correct answer as stated below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have a *dat.txt* file with the following content:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Then you can do this, to get a cell array with vectors which each holds the values of one row:

```
f = fopen('dat.txt');   
g = textscan(f,'%f%f%[^\n\r]')
fclose(f)

gdat = [g{1:end-1}];

for i=1:length(g{1,1})
  NVar{i} = gdat(i, :);
end
```

You can access these vectors in the cell array *NVar* like that: `NVar{1}`, `NVar{2}`

Edit: I am using MATLAB R2012b, but I guess these basic functions should work in Octave without a problem.

Comment: Thanks works fine. I have an option to work on ocatave or matlab for my project so I framed it such. But works with both.